# How to "show windows stacked" from console app?

Tags: c#, winapi, console-application

Does anyone know about a way to arrange all windows on the desktop, when one app restarts itself?

When a lot of console windows run on the desktop simultaneously, you can manually use the "show windows stacked" or "show windows side by side" command.

I'd like my app to do the same from time to time, ideally at the moment when it restarts itself. In this case it's Windows 7 64bit.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Stopwatch instanceStopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    instanceStopwatch.Start();
    while (instanceStopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds < 600000) //not stable enough to run longer
    {
        //work for 10 minutes
    }
    Process.Start(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0], Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[1]); //restart yourself before you quit

    // COMMAND WINDOWS TO SHOW WINDOWS STACKED HERE
}
```

Comment: Find all the windows, and move them to where you want them to be

Comment: Do you know what .NET libraries/frameworks do exist for that?

Comment: I don't think there are any